# return new MongoError('Cannot use a session that has ended'); MongoError: Cannot use a session that has ended

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Essentially, I am trying to update the winner's points and remove points from the losers, but for some reason, the connection closes before the loop finishes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 module.exports.PointDistrubtion = async (winnerId, price, buyIn, losersId) => {
            return await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
                try {
                    
                    await profileSchema
                        .findOneAndUpdate(
                            {
                                userId: winnerId,
                            },
                            {
                                $inc: {
                                    Points: price - buyIn,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                upsert: true,
                                new: true,
                            }
                        )
                        .then(
                            losersId.forEach(async (userId) => {
                                await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
                                    {
                                        userId,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $inc: {
                                            Points: -BuyIn,
                                        },
                                    },
                                    {
                                        upsert: true,
                                        new: true,
                                    }
                                );
                            })
                        );
                } finally {
                    mongoose.connection.close();
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this should work:

```
module.exports.PointDistrubtion = async (winnerId, price, buyIn, losersId) => {
  return await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
    try {
      await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userId: winnerId,
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            Points: price - buyIn,
          },
        },
        {
          upsert: true,
          new: true,
        },
      );

      await Promise.all(
        losersId.map(async (userId) => {
          await profileSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
              userId,
            },
            {
              $inc: {
                Points: -BuyIn,
              },
            },
            {
              upsert: true,
              new: true,
            },
          );
        }),
      );
    } finally {
      mongoose.connection.close();
    }
  });
};
```